# Changing View Port on button click in HTML5, CSS3, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to change the view of site on a button click in HTML 5 Fluid Grids, for instance when I click button with mobile phone, my site view changes to Mobile View or you can say my view port changes to mobile and similarly when I click tab view it switch itself to tab view port and start showing tab site.
My site is already in fluid grid system. Mean when I change the size of browser windows it changes, but I want to get this effect using a button click.
For reference take a look at this link. Want to achieve functionality similar to 4 buttons on right of it.
http://themeforest.net/item/diverso-bootstrap-responsive-sliding-pages/full_screen_preview/4919410

Comment: They are embedding an iframe (essentially another document) within that page.  When you click on an icon it resizes the iframe.  They are likely using jQuery `on('click' function() {})` to do this.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was actually confused. I was searching for some function which could dynamically change viewport of complete site. But thanks for giving me the direction, This will totally work. I guess i will be posting a solution to my Question myself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="tvResize();"><img src="tv.gif"></button>
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

... The above two are the critical HTML.  Add buttons for each function, and you will want to position the canvas where you'd like it ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var v = yourVideo
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = base.getContext('2d');
    var w, h;

    function tvResize() {
        w = "400px" 
        h = "100px"
        canvas.width = w
        canvas.height = h
        }

    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)

    function draw() {
    context.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h)
        }
```

take a look at this for positioning ideas:  [someone named notme](http://jsfiddle.net/notme/RMydz/)
You can then create one for "laptopResize", "phoneResize", "skinnyThingResize", etc.